# If an integrable function has a nonnegative integral over any set of a generating algebra, then it has a nonnegative integral over any measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, proof-verification, monotone-class-theorem

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space
- $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)$ and $$\mathcal M:=\left\{A\in\mathcal A:\int_Af\:{\rm d}\mu\ge0\right\}$$
- $\mathcal E\subseteq\mathcal M$ be an algebra with $\sigma(\mathcal E)=\mathcal A$

> I want to conclude that $$\int_Af\:{\rm d}\mu\ge0\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal A\;.\tag1$$

Using the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), we should be able to show that $\mathcal M$ is a monotone class and hence $$\mathcal A=\sigma(\mathcal E)\subseteq\mathcal M\subseteq\mathcal A\tag2$$ by the [monotone class theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Statement). Is there any mistake in my argumentation?

Moreover, I'm curious whether or not we're able to relax the assumption of being an algebra on $\mathcal E$. In particular, I've found a proof where the author is assuming that $\mathcal E$ is only closed under complement. I've asked [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353497/is-the-assumption-of-being-an-algebra-crucial-in-the-monotone-class-theorem) for that.

Comment: You seem to define $\mathcal{A}$ before and after $\mathcal{M}$ ?

Comment: @Adam No, why do you think that? $\mathcal A$ is defined only once as the $\sigma$-algebra of the measure space. $\mathcal E$ is defined to be a generator of $\mathcal A$ and hence we have the relation $\mathcal A=\sigma(\mathcal E)$.

Comment: This looks right to me.